# Insert a script at the top of HEAD tag in PageMod (Firefox Add-on SDK)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to insert a script in Firefox Add-on SDK content script added via  [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod). So, when user goes to page XXX, he gets a page with the inserted script. But, when trying to insert this at the top of HEAD, I got an error that the 1st Node child is not an object.

My content script code with which I insert the `<script>` is:

```
script='<script>var d=new Date(2012,2,24); window.Date=function () {return d;}</script>';

var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
```

What's with it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a *complete* [mcve].  That means all the files needed for a minimal add-on. What is actually happening depends on significantly more than the 3 lines of code you have shown (although, there are obvious issues).

Comment: Please provide the *exact* error text you see in either the console, or in the shell from which you run `jpm run`.

Comment: Note that injecting `<script>` tags from addons is discouraged since they run in the untrusted page context. The addon script already has access to the DOM anyway and can interact with DOM events so there rarely is a reason to do this.

Comment: Thanks! It works. About untrusted contents is specially of interest. But here we can check the page contents. Good theme to think and talk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thus, this answer is based just on the code you have provided.

### **Issue with how you are using [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore):**

The first issue I noticed is that you are providing a string as the first argument to [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) when that argument needs to be a [node object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).

However, you state the error you are getting is "1st Node child is not an object". This does not match what I would expect from an error based on the code provided.  When I put your code in a [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) content script, the error I got was:

```
console.error: testpagemodinsertBefore:
Object
    - _errorType = TypeError
    - message = Argument 1 of Node.insertBefore is not an object.
    - fileName = resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://testpagemodinsertbefore/data/contentScript.js
    - lineNumber = 26
    - stack = @resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://testpagemodinsertbefore/data/contentScript.js:26:1|
    - name = TypeError
```

This is the error which I would expect from the code in the question.  Thus, you have either not posted the code which is producing the error you have stated, or you have inaccurately reported the error which you saw in the console. In the future, please be *exact* in what you are reporting. Being more verbose is better than leaving things out.

### **Inserting HTML text:**

Your code:

```
script='<script>var d=new Date(2012,2,24); window.Date=function () {return d;}</script>';
```

defines some HTML text which you are trying to insert into the DOM.
If you want to insert HTML text instead of inserting nodes, one way for you to do so is to use [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). One way you could do this in your code is:

```
head.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',script);
```

This works well for most HTML. But, does not result in the contents of the `<script>` tag being executed/evaluated. This is [for security reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations). It is *much* easier for an attacker to get arbitrary text inserted into the DOM than it is for them to insert actual nodes/elements. The HTML specification specifies that a  tag inserted inserted as text [will not be executed](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0).

### **Inserting a `<script>` tag that is evaluated and executed:**

We can do this by creating a `<script>` element containing the script text desired, then inserting that element into the DOM.

For your code that would look something like:

```js
//Get the first <head> element
let head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

//The script text desired
let scriptText='var d=new Date(2012,2,24); window.Date=function () {return d;};';

//Add an alert for testing (\n is not needed. But, is more readable when inspecting DOM.)
scriptText = 'window.alert("In inserted script");\n' + scriptText;

//Create a <script> element
let scriptEl = document.createElement( 'script' );
//That is JavaScript
scriptEl.type = 'text/javascript'; 
//Add the script text
scriptEl.textContent = scriptText;
//Insert it as the firstChild of <head>
head.insertBefore( scriptEl, head.firstChild );
```

### **Further reading:**

You appear to be desire to interact with page scripts using your content script.  I suggest that you read the MDN page "[Interacting with page scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts)".

Comment: Sorry, this is really your type of error. I have an error - insertBefore really in the console.

Comment: @user2543953, I have updated this answer to show how you can insert a `<script>` such that it is evaluated and executed.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot. You saved me a lot of time. Interesting topic.

Comment: Mozilla documentation can be more clear, though. But at last it began working!!

Comment: One more question - can we define somehow the parameters so the plugin can be executed with them? for example with command line parameters. If several browsers will be executed with this XPI.

Comment: And would be good to define the timezone in Date(). :) This is for happy end.